# no overload for method "sqlQuery" takes 0 arguments - c# error

Tags: c#

I am trying to run an ActionResult and am getting the zero arguments error stating 'No Overload for Method 'SqlQuery' takes 0 arguments.' Here is my ActionResult:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Carriers()
    {

        string sqlStr = "Select CarrierKey, Name From carriers Order By Name";
        var AllCarriers = db.Database.SqlQuery<CarrierList>().ToList();

        var ListofCarriers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AllCarriers);

        Response.Write(ListofCarriers);
        HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return new EmptyResult(); 

    }
```

I have set up the following class for my results:

```
   public class CarrierList
    {
        public int CarrierKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I have read a little about this error and it seems to happen when a parameter is expected but not received or vice versa. As far as I can tell I am not setting my query up for a parameter so I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your query to `SqlQuery` method:

```
var AllCarriers = db.Database.SqlQuery<CarrierList>(sqlStr).ToList();
```